# Custom template is not loading in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am using wpestate real wordpress theme. I have created my custom template for requirement post type and apply it to the page called Add requirement. But it's not loading template??It displays correct url in browser but it display blank white screen.

Comment: Try flushing the permalinks - Settings -> Permalinks -> Set to default, hit save and then put it back how it was, hit save again.

Comment: How are you loading the theme? oh and there are hundreds of reasons for a white screen of death - http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#The_White_Screen_of_Death

Comment: If you bought the theme, why don't you ask on their official support?

Comment: Try disabling all plugins then load the site. there may be a conflict or misconfiguration somewhere and not all plugins work with all themes. If it loads ok witghout plugins, add them back again one-by-one refreshing the site each time to find if it is a plugin.